# Trying to get the ID of a Live Video from Youtube

Tags: youtube-api, google-apis-explorer

I am trying to get the Video ID the YouTube generates when we go live.  I am trying to link a live video with the live comments widgets on my website!

My current query string is: `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId=UC4fb76SWvttKJ1T6a2g6yIw&eventType=live&key=[YOUR_API_KEY]`

```js
{
  "error": {
    "errors": [{
      "domain": "youtube.search",
      "reason": "invalidSearchFilter",
      "message": "The request contains an invalid combination of search filters and/or restrictions. Note that you must set the \u003ccode\u003etype\u003c/code\u003e parameter to \u003ccode\u003evideo\u003c/code\u003e if you set either the \u003ccode\u003eforContentOwner\u003c/code\u003e or \u003ccode\u003eforMine\u003c/code\u003e parameters to \u003ccode\u003etrue\u003c/code\u003e. You must also set the \u003ccode\u003etype\u003c/code\u003e parameter to \u003ccode\u003evideo\u003c/code\u003e if you set a value for the \u003ccode\u003eeventType\u003c/code\u003e, \u003ccode\u003evideoCaption\u003c/code\u003e, \u003ccode\u003evideoCategoryId\u003c/code\u003e, \u003ccode\u003evideoDefinition\u003c/code\u003e, \u003ccode\u003evideoDimension\u003c/code\u003e, \u003ccode\u003evideoDuration\u003c/code\u003e, \u003ccode\u003evideoEmbeddable\u003c/code\u003e, \u003ccode\u003evideoLicense\u003c/code\u003e, \u003ccode\u003evideoSyndicated\u003c/code\u003e, or \u003ccode\u003evideoType\u003c/code\u003e parameters.",
      "locationType": "parameter",
      "location": ""
    }],
    "code": 400,
    "message": "The request contains an invalid combination of search filters and/or restrictions. Note that you must set the \u003ccode\u003etype\u003c/code\u003e parameter to \u003ccode\u003evideo\u003c/code\u003e if you set either the \u003ccode\u003eforContentOwner\u003c/code\u003e or \u003ccode\u003eforMine\u003c/code\u003e parameters to \u003ccode\u003etrue\u003c/code\u003e. You must also set the \u003ccode\u003etype\u003c/code\u003e parameter to \u003ccode\u003evideo\u003c/code\u003e if you set a value for the \u003ccode\u003eeventType\u003c/code\u003e, \u003ccode\u003evideoCaption\u003c/code\u003e, \u003ccode\u003evideoCategoryId\u003c/code\u003e, \u003ccode\u003evideoDefinition\u003c/code\u003e, \u003ccode\u003evideoDimension\u003c/code\u003e, \u003ccode\u003evideoDuration\u003c/code\u003e, \u003ccode\u003evideoEmbeddable\u003c/code\u003e, \u003ccode\u003evideoLicense\u003c/code\u003e, \u003ccode\u003evideoSyndicated\u003c/code\u003e, or \u003ccode\u003evideoType\u003c/code\u003e parameters."
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the **type** parameter to video to get past the 400 error.  So an example URL would be:

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId=UC4fb76SWvttKJ1T6a2g6yIw&eventType=live&t**ype=video**&key=[YOUR_API_KEY]

Having said all that I get a 200 response but empty items array.  So I continue to fight this problem as well.